# Derivative formalism question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

After seeing a lot of integrals going like $$\int f(x,y) \,dxdy = \int f(x,y)\,dA$$ I am wondering wether it is allowed to write something like this:
$$\frac{d f(x,y)}{dA} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}$$
when defining $dA = \partial x \partial y$. Obviously f(x,y) is not dependent of A, but $\int f(x,y) \, dxdy$ is also not dependent on A, so is it formally correct?
Same question goes for Volume:
$$\frac{d f(x,y,z)}{dV} = \frac{\partial^3 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y \partial z}$$.

Comment: You can define it that way if you want, but really $dA$ is not about $dx dy$, and $dV$ is not about $dx dy dz$. It's "the differential that you integrate against 1 to get area" (or volume). So in particular there is no real meaning to $\frac{\partial^2 f}{r \partial r \partial \theta}$. Yet you would expect that to be the same as $\frac{df}{dA}$ based on your line of thinking.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. In Riemannian geometry, $dA$ and $dV$ are shortcuts for the expression $$dV=\sqrt{g}dx_1\ldots dx_n, $$ where $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor. This has not much to do with partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks. So I was interpreting it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formalism you wrote doesn't really make sense. You are defining a derivative as a second (and third) derivative. So, for instance,  you are saying that $df/dV =0$ when $f (x,y,z)=xy^2+5y^2z^2$.

When writing a double  integral, $dA $ signifies the area elements that you are using in your Riemann sums, namely small rectangles. When the integral exists  (say, when $f $ is continuous) the double integral can be calculated via iterated integrals, so $dA $ is effectively $dxdy $.

The point of view of the integral as an antiderivative (that is, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) is crucial for one-variable integrals but doesn't really have higher-dimensional extensions.

Comment: The thing with one derivative beeing a second derivative was confusing me as well. That is why i was asking. Thanks for clearing it up.